# Why the heroku server shut downs after few minutes?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, rest, heroku

I developed a REST API to a project and i tryed to upload it to **Heroku**. At the moment when i start the app, it runs for a few minutes and crashes.

Any help is useful, thanks in advance.

Some data, tables and variables that i use are in spanish, sorry. :/

### STRUCTURE

- node_modules
- requests (some http requests to test)
- .gitignore
- app.js
- package-lock.json
- package.json

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trGzH.png)

### THE CODE

This is **the only JavaScript file** that i use in the project.
PS: I changed the connection info, for security

```js
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3050;

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

//MySql
var cnx = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'any_host',
    user: 'any_user',
    password: 'any_password',
    database: 'any_database'
});

//rutas
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Bienvenido a mi API');
});

app.get('/usuarios', (req, res) => {
    const sql = 'SELECT * FROM usuario';
    cnx.query(sql, (error, results) => {
        if (error) throw error;

        if(results.length > 0){
            res.json(results);
        }else{
            res.send('No hay resultados')
        }
    });
});

app.get('/usuarios/:id', (req, res) => {

    const { id } = req.params;
    const sql = `SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE idusuario = ${id}`;

    cnx.query(sql, (error, result) => {
        if (error) throw error;

        if (resul.length > 0) {
            res.json(result);
        }else{
            res.send('No hay resultados');
        }
    });
});

app.post('/add', (req, res) => {
    const sql = 'INSERT INTO usuario SET ?';

    const saltRounds = 10;
    const contraseñaHash = bcrypt.hash(req.body.contraseña, saltRounds);
    const usuarioObj = {
        cuenta: req.body.cuenta,
        contraseña: contraseñaHash,
        nombre: req.body.nombre,
        apellido: req.body.apellido
    };

    cnx.query(sql, usuarioObj, error => {
        if (error) throw error;
        res.send('Usuario creado');
    });
});

app.put('/update/:id', (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const { cuenta, contraseña, nombre, apellido } = req.body;
    var sql = mysql.format(
        'UPDATE usuario SET cuenta = ?, contraseña = ?, nombre = ?, apellido = ? WHERE idusuario = ?',
        [cuenta, contraseña, nombre, apellido, id]
    );

    cnx.query(sql, error => {
        if(error) throw error;
        res.send('Usuario actualizado!');
    });
});

app.delete('/delete/:id', (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    var sql = `DELETE FROM usuario WHERE idusuario = ${id}`;

    cnx.query(sql, error =>{
        if(error) throw error;
        res.send('Usuario eliminado!');
    });
});

// Check connect
cnx.connect(error => {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log('Corriendo base de datos');
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`El servidor esta corriendo en el puerto ${PORT}`));
```

This is the **package.json**

```js
{
  "name": "api_madison",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "2.0.12"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "5.0.1",
    "body-parser": "1.19.0",
    "mysql": "2.18.1",
    "express": "4.17.1"
  }
}
```

And this is the **.gitignore**

```js
/node_modules/
```

### HEROKU

The API works well for a few minutes, then stops working.

- Api working well

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0zuo.png)

- Api down

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzyNN.png)

### CLI HEROKU

When i start the command `heroku logs --tail`, this appears

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpoHW.png)

```js
2021-10-05T06:03:15.581449+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/usuarios" host=apimadison.herokuapp.com request_id=6deca321-588c-411d-b81a-e231eacb6eaf fwd="190.42.207.86" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=38ms status=200 bytes=2352 protocol=https
2021-10-05T06:04:15.512510+00:00 app[web.1]: events.js:377
2021-10-05T06:04:15.512519+00:00 app[web.1]: throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2021-10-05T06:04:15.512519+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-10-05T06:04:15.512520+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-10-05T06:04:15.512521+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
2021-10-05T06:04:15.512521+00:00 app[web.1]: at Protocol.end (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:112:13)
2021-10-05T06:04:15.512522+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:94:28)
2021-10-05T06:04:15.512522+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
2021-10-05T06:04:15.512522+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.emit (events.js:412:35)
2021-10-05T06:04:15.512522+00:00 app[web.1]: at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1334:12)
2021-10-05T06:04:15.512523+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
2021-10-05T06:04:15.512524+00:00 app[web.1]: Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:
2021-10-05T06:04:15.512526+00:00 app[web.1]: at Connection._handleProtocolError (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:423:8)
2021-10-05T06:04:15.512527+00:00 app[web.1]: at Protocol.emit (events.js:400:28)
2021-10-05T06:04:15.512527+00:00 app[web.1]: at Protocol._delegateError (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:398:10)
2021-10-05T06:04:15.512527+00:00 app[web.1]: at Protocol.end (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:116:8)
2021-10-05T06:04:15.512528+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:94:28)
2021-10-05T06:04:15.512528+00:00 app[web.1]: [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
2021-10-05T06:04:15.512529+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
2021-10-05T06:04:15.512529+00:00 app[web.1]: fatal: true,
2021-10-05T06:04:15.512529+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST'
2021-10-05T06:04:15.512529+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-10-05T06:04:15.525602+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-10-05T06:04:15.525824+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2021-10-05T06:04:15.530954+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! api_madison@1.0.0 start: `node .`
2021-10-05T06:04:15.531050+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2021-10-05T06:04:15.531156+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-10-05T06:04:15.531244+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the api_madison@1.0.0 start script.
2021-10-05T06:04:15.531322+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-10-05T06:04:15.540307+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-10-05T06:04:15.542432+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-10-05T06:04:15.542504+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-10-05T06_04_15_531Z-debug.log
2021-10-05T06:04:15.709436+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-10-05T06:04:15.760747+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-10-05T06:07:24.606771+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/usuarios" host=apimadison.herokuapp.com request_id=231283ff-9748-4690-bd38-9f6e358673fe fwd="190.42.207.86" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Incidentally, with `heroku restart`, the API works again, but has the same problem.

THANK YOU FOR YOUR TIME

Comment: Its seeming that you have connection problem. You're getting error at first query (method=GET path="/usuarios"). So you may check your db connection info and settings.

Comment: The first line is about the load of `/usuarios` and returns status = 200. But i'll check the database. 

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is the connection is timing out. Best practice here is to create a new connection for each query and close it after rather than having a single connection.

Comment: Perhaps with the `cnx.end()` line for each end point. I will try it. 